# Why does ECHO = 8 off the bat in SWIFT?

Tags: macos, xcode6, swift-playground

new to Swift, was just wondering why ECHO is equal to 8 in Swift. Puzzling me.

[image: SCREENSHOT OF SWIFT PLAYGROUND]

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by <kbd>⌥</kbd>-clicking on the symbol.

It's defined in `sys/termios.h` in section `Local flags`

```
#define ECHO        0x00000008  /* enable echoing */
```